# No module named 'torch.nn'; 'torch' is not a packageのエラーを直したい

Tags: python, pytorch

pytorchをインストールして、インストールできたことも確認したのですが、以下のエラーが発生してしまいます。どなたか解決法をご教示お願い致します。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
import torch.nn as nn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.nn'; 'torch' is not a packages
```

**ソースコード**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
# # 初期重みの関数
def init_weight(size):
    f = size[0]
    v = 1. / np.sqrt(f)
    return torch.tensor(np.random.uniform(low=v, high=v, size=size), dtype=torch.float)
```

**実行環境**
Python 3.7.9
torch 1.9.0
torchaudio 0.9.0
torchvision 0.10.0

Comment: Tutorialの [Refactor using nn.Module](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nn_tutorial.html#refactor-using-nn-module) だと、`from torch import nn` としているようです。例えば [PyTorchでモデル（ネットワーク）を構築・生成](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pytorch-module-sequential/) の冒頭の注意 `本記事におけるPyTorchのバージョンは以下の通り。バージョンが異なると仕様が異なる可能性があるので注意。` にあるように、何か使い方が変わったのかもしれません。Tutorialのやり方を試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ちなみにWindows10の素のPythonだと、3.7.9, 3.8.10, 3.9.5 のいずれも質問の`import torch.nn as nn`で動作しました。何か環境問題か、表面に出てこないインストール依存関係とかあるのかもしれません。

Comment: カレントディレクトリに `torch.py` というファイルがありませんか？(もしくは掲示のソースコードのファイル名が `torch.py` になっているとか)

Comment: metropolisさんコメントの状態が一番ありそうですね。